# Issue with countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

can someone explain me, why when I press plus and then start, timer increase the the minutes? For example if I set minutes eqaul to 10, timer starts to count from 11. When I press minus the same problem occurs. I am trying to do pomodoro clock, but first I have to fix this problem :P Thanks for any help!

Here is my code

```
  var flag = false;
  var timer;
  var work = 2;
  var count = 0;

  $('.mins').html(updateNum(work));
  $('.secs').html(updateNum(count));


function workTimer() {
  if(count < 0) {
    work--;
    count = 59;
  }
  if (work<0) {
    return clearInterval(timer);
  }



  $('.mins').html(updateNum(work));
  $('.secs').html(updateNum(count));
  count--;
}
$('.start-button').click(function() {
  if (flag == false) {

    timer=setInterval(workTimer,1000);
    $(this).html("stop");
            flag = true;
            return flag;
  }
  else if(flag == true){

      clearInterval(timer);
      $(this).html("start");
      flag = false;
      return flag;
  }
})



$('.session-plus').click(function() {
  if(flag == false) {
    console.log(work);
    $('.mins').html(updateNum(work++));
  }

})

$('.session-minus').click(function() {
  if(flag == false) {
          $('.mins').html(updateNum(work--));
  }

})

function updateNum(num) {
  if(num < 10) {
      return num = "0" + num;
  }
  else {
      return num;
  }

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wved99o3/

#edit
I do not want to do another topic, so I have next problem. My timer doesn't count from 0 as you can see. Timer adds every time 1 extra second. I have no idea why :/

https://jsfiddle.net/6vnkgt3h/

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.mins').html(updateNum(work++));
```

You need to swap your ++ to preceed the variable.

```
$('.mins').html(updateNum(++work));
```

With the ++ being after the variable, the old value will be passed in, not the new value.  By putting the ++ in front, it performs the increment before passing in the value.